# What does @Transient annotation mean for methods?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, annotations, transient

So I have learned that the `transient` keyword in Java means that an entity does not persist, and that the `@Transient` annotation in JPA means don't persist a field to the database. But what does it mean when `@Transient` is applied to a method rather than a variable?

This is where I found it in our code:

```
@Transient
public boolean getTabFoo() {
    if ((this.viewFoo1 != ACCESS_NONE)
            || (this.viewFoo2 != ACCESS_NONE) || (this.viewFoo3 != ACCESS_NONE)
            || (this.getViewFoo4() != ACCESS_NONE)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All field-level JPA annotations can be placed either on fields or on properties, it determines access type of the entity (i.e. how JPA provider will access fields of that entity - directly or using getters/setters).

Default access type is determined by placement of `@Id` annotation, and it should be consistent for all fields of the entity (or hiererchy of inherited entities), unless explicitly overriden by `@Access` for some fields.

So, `@Transient` on getters has the same meaning as `@Transient` on fields - if default access type for your entity is property access, you need to annotate all getters that don't correspond to persistent properties with `@Transient`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it much clearer. So it's only being used on a method because it's a getter, then?

Comment: What if the `AccessType` is indeed `Field`, but `@Transient` is still used on a `Getter method` (and its not a simple one line getter directly associate with a Field (regarding the naming convention))? [eg this](https://github.com/Apress/pro-spring-5/blob/master/chapter16/singer-webapp-jcfg/src/main/java/com/apress/prospring5/ch16/entities/Singer.java)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a proper getter method, which JPA by default will assume is bound to an entity property. If you don't want JPA to treat a getter as a property, you apply the `@Transient` annotation to the method.