# Can I map one single field to two columns in the database using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Consider the following Java Hibernate Entity example (code snippet):

```
...

@Column
@Converter(...)
private String columnOne;

public String getcolumnOne() {
    return columnOne;
}

public setColumnOne(String columnOne) {
    this.columnOne = columnOne;
}

...
```

This will generate a `COLUMN_ONE` is the database.

How can/should I generate a 2nd column `COLUMN_TWO` in the database table that is generated from the same field `columnOne` field? This 2nd column is not important in the Java code that uses this Entity, so my Entity should not export this 2nd column to the user of this Entity. `COLUMN_TWO` will be used in the database itself (for some indexing) and by other applications.

Comment: A very unusual case, in the setter of column one set value for both column or create a generated column in the database. And if you don't want to fetch a column you can select columns using @Query

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63981986/6277104) is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* I haven't tried this, but I believe Hibernate can access private methods, since it can access private fields.

For this example, let's say you have a property of type `LocalDateTime`, as seen by the user of the class, but that you want to store the value as strings (`VARCHAR`) in ISO-8601 format, with date in one column and time in another column.

So you have your normal `private` field and normal `public` getter/setter methods. You don't put `@Column` on either, but instead use `@Transient` to make JPA ignore the property.

You then create two derived getter/setter pairs of methods, make them `private` so they can't be seen by users of the class, and then annotate both pairs with `@Column`, to make JPA use them when persisting in the database.

```java
private LocalDateTime dateTime;

@Transient // Do not persist in database
public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
    return this.dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

@Column(name = "FOO_DATE", nullable = true, length = 10)
private String getDate() {
    if (this.dateTime == null)
        return null;
    return this.dateTime.toLocalDate().toString();
}

private void setDate(String date) {
    if (date == null) {
        this.dateTime = null;
    } else {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(date);
        LocalTime time = (this.dateTime == null ? LocalTime.MIDNIGHT
                          : this.dateTime.toLocalTime());
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date, time);
    }
}

@Column(name = "FOO_TIME", nullable = true, length = 12)
private String getTime() {
    if (this.dateTime == null)
        return null;
    return this.dateTime.toLocalTime()
               .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
}

private void setTime(String time) {
    if (time == null) {
        this.dateTime = null;
    } else {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(time);
        LocalDate date = (this.dateTime == null ? LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0)
                          : this.dateTime.toLocalDate());
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date, time);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think using @Transient on getter works to store in database as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477034/what-does-transient-annotation-mean-for-methods `@Transient on getters has the same meaning as @Transient on fields`

Comment: @Eklavya The answers in the link specifically says that `@Transient` does work on methods for suppressing/disabling persistence.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide if you want your database design to be driven by your entity design or if you want to decouple the two.

If you don't need the column in your entity, then simply don't map it. If your "problem" with that approach is, that hbm2ddl doesn't generate the column you have to decide if the entity model should really be the driver for the database design. You could (and IMO should) use a tool like Liquibase or Flyway to do the database schema migrations. This way, you can have the column in the database and at the same time not map it in the entity.

I understand that this might be too much for your little use case, but I recommend you do this eventually because you will need it at some point. Anyway, you could also just map it as private field without exposing the field.